# Entity Framework Linq Update Table

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity

I am using Entity Framework 6 Code First, all of my navigation properties looks correct. What I want to do in linq is to update multiple values in the one (entity) table with calculated values from the other (entity) table. The required outcome is the sql below,

```
UPDATE SalesDealItemChange
 SET Price = SD.Rate * @FactorRate
 FROM SalesDealItemChange SC
 INNER JOIN [SalesDealItems] SD
    ON SC.SalesDealItemID = sd.ID
 WHERE SD.SalesDealID = @SalesDeal
```

I have tried the following linq, but i am not sure how to isolate the update to the SalesDealItemChange

```
 context.SalesDealItems
    .Include(x => x.SalesDealItemChanges)
    .Where(x => x.SalesDealID == @SalesDeal)
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
    x.SalesDealItemChanges.Price = x.ListPrice * @FactorRate;
    });

context.SaveChanges();
```

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "isolate"? From what?

Comment: Thanks Gert, what I mean is that I only want to update the SalesDealItemChanges entity with the calculated value from the SalesDealItems.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what you're doing now (provided that you get the code running). EF won't save anything but `SalesDealItemChanges` entities.